# Force C++ initialiser to require exact number of array items

Tags: c++

Consider the following code snippet:

```
struct Test
{
   char name[ 9 ];
};

Test gv_Test[ ] = {
   { "a" },
   { "12345678" },
   { "longstri" }
};
```

This code will compile fine. If I change "longstri" to "longstring" I will get a compiler error because I have overflowed the array.

My question is: is there a way to get the compiler to error if I don't provide the exact number of bytes/chars per the array? In other words, error on "underflow", such as the "a" example?

It would be useful for me as a compile-time check to ensure that each "name" in the above example was exactly 8 chars plus terminator.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to enforce that `Test` gets initialized with an array of size 9.  You can do this by giving `Test` a constructor that takes a `const char[9]` by reference.  In doing so only a string literal of size 8 can be used to construct the object object.

Here is an example of this:

```
struct Test
{
    Test(const char (&str)[9]) { std::copy(str, str + 9, name); }
    char name[ 9 ];
};

Test gv_Test[ ] = {
    { "a" },
    { "12345678" },
    { "longstri0" }
};

int main()
{
    
}
```

and [the errors you get from g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2401b20feb3f03ee) are

```
main.cpp:29:1: error: could not convert '{"a"}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Test'
   29 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | <brace-enclosed initializer list>
main.cpp:29:1: error: could not convert '{"longstri0"}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Test'
   29 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

showing that a too small or large of a literal generates an error but `{ "12345678" }` compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a template function
Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/fOQt2W6jX

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

// compile time function template
// size_v = lenght of the string used as input
template<std::size_t size_v>
static constexpr const char* str_of_len(const char(&c)[size_v])
{
    return c;
}

struct test_t
{
    const char* s[2] =
    {
        str_of_len<9>("12345678"),
        str_of_len<9>("abcdefgh"),
        // str_of_len<9>("1234567"), <== this line wil not compile
    };
};

int main()
{
    test_t test;
    std::cout << test.s[1] << "\n";
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your SFINAE is unneeded, just can use `size_v` in a non-deducible context: `template<std::size_t size_v>
static constexpr auto str_of_len(const char(&c)[std::intergal_constant<std::size_t, size_v>::value])`.

Comment: @Jarod42 you're right, sometimes it is easy to forget the obvious  ;) Example updated